# How to pass angular JS value in URL as parameters

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have the following link

```
<a href="entity-details.html?id='{{ x.community_id }}&community_society_id={{x.community_society_id}}">View</a>
```

I want  x.community_id and x.community_society_id values to pass to a controller then later I fetch the data.

```
var app = angular.module('EntityApp', []);
app.controller('EntityAppCntroller', function($scope, $http, $location) {   
    var myParamtr = location.search.split('id=')[1] ? location.search.split('id=')[1] : 'myDefaultValue';   
    alert(myParamtr);
    $http.get('apartment/community/details/list/'+ myParam).then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.list;
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of `href`, use `ng-href`

Comment: Ok but I think in anchor tag syntax is wrong I think can u solve it.?

Comment: If it is ng-model value then you dont have to pass it to the controller, the scope variable will be available in your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ng-href so the values can be built into the link.  Lke @tanmay said in the comments.

```
<a ng-href="entity-details.html?id={{ x.community_id }}&community_society_id={{x.community_society_id}}">View</a>
```

change the controller to parse the url correctly.

```
var app = angular.module('EntityApp', []);
app.controller('EntityAppCntroller', function($scope, $http, $location) {   

     var getJsonFromUrl = function(url) {
        console.log(url);
        var query = url.substr(1);
        var result = {};
        query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
          var item = part.split("=");
          result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
        });
        return result;
     };

    var queryParams = getJsonFromUrl(location.search);

    var myParamtr = queryParams.id ? queryParams.id : 'myDefaultValue';   

    alert(myParamtr);

    $http.get('apartment/community/details/list/'+ myParam).then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.list;
    });

});
```

Comment: But in controller am receiving a value like this junk..  3&community_society_ I want only 3 not &community_society_. I think I stuck in anchor tag.. Cn u solve this.?

Comment: you had an extra ' in the href you posted.

Comment: I removed it.. But am getting junk value in controller. I dont know why.?

Comment: you had that as part of the href.  just remove the &community.... It looks like you were passing 2 parameters

Comment: Yes it is second parameter.. I needed it.. I removed & but not working....

Comment: also it might be an issue in the controller.  in the split you don't have a $ on location.  var myParamtr = $location.search.split('id=')[1] ? $location.search.split('id=')[1] : 'myDefaultValue';   
    alert(myParamtr);

Comment: It will work, it will use $location that you are injection into the controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141640/discussion-between-michael-and-prashanth).